# Hide Black Screen While Pushing ViewController With Animation

Tags: ios, cgaffinetransform

I am new to iOS development. I am using the following code:

```
AskViewController *askController=[[AskViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AskViewController" bundle:nil];
askController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01); 
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animationExpand" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedDuration];
askController.view.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:askController animated:NO];
```

When I push askViewcontroller to the navigation, It shows me the AskViewcontroller with animation with black screen. I want to change that black screen to white or any other color Screen.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method of your app delegate, add this line :

```
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set askController.view's backgroundColor, for example:

```
[askController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

It will set your askController.view's backgroundColor to green.

Comment: It Will Set the askViewController View's background as a green color, But i want the transition black screen into white of any other color if Possible.

Comment: Try [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         [askController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"Done!");
                     }];   greenColor could change to other pre-defined UIColour. OR use RGB to set any other colour if you want